# Login using Google OAuth 2.0 with .NetCore

Tags: .net-core

I want to allow User to login using Gmail through the OAuth2 process.

I don't use Razor as a client it is the reason why did not use the auth template.

My stack is ReactJs and .Net core 2.2.

I have registered my Project and got Secret KEY & Client ID. Now I want to integrate it my Project but I am unable to find any sample working Project.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: There's a [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in the docs that explains the basic setup for logging in to your ASP.NET Core app using only Google. Does that help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of login and google/callback functions?